# How to resize a sprite in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

I have a problem with the method `sprite.setSize(float x, float y)` in Libgdx. It does not affect the size or the dimensions of the sprite. They remains fixed whatever I pass to the setSize() method.

**here is my code**:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    OrthographicCamera camera;

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture carTexture;
    Sprite carSprite;

    public GameScreen()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
            carSprite.setSize(16, 32);
            batch.draw(carSprite, 0 , 0);
        batch.end();
        camera.update();    
}

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.viewportWidth=width;
        camera.viewportHeight=height;
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        carTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("NetRace.png"));
        carTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

        carSprite = new Sprite(carTexture);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

could you please find my mistake?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem was solved.

I had to use `sprite.draw(batch);` instead of using `Batch.draw(Sprite sp, float x, float y);` since the `Batch.draw(...)` method takes the texture from the passed sprite and uses the texture in the drawing process which has a fixed width and a fixed height.

Another way to solve this problem is to use the `batch.draw(Sprite, float x, float y, float width, float height);` method in the `SpriteBatch` class.

Comment: This solution is also a solution to a different problem: reducing the size of a Pixmap. If you use the Sprite.setScale() function instead of setSize() it scales the Pixmap (wrapped in a Texture) accurately. This has been a problem:  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2732#issuecomment-74154416